# Working of hadoop

Tags: hadoop

How exactly does hadoop's map-reduce work?

Say, I have a program with a set of instructions, each dependant on the previous one and can only be executed on completion of the previous instruction. Can hadoop's map-reduce be used for such a scenario?

If I submit that program, how would the algorithm work exactly?

Sorry if I am asking a dumb question. I am trying to understand the map reduce algorithm in depth. If I search online, I can only find the word count problem as an example, which does not have any dependency with in the program for accessing a resource. I tried looking into source code, but it is too difficult to understand the structure.

Also, if you can suggest me some material for getting in depth knowledge on hadoop, that would be really great.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: This is a very good question, but a bit too broad for this platform. Try reading "Hadoop: The definitive guide". (+1 Close Vote)

Comment: @axiom Thanks for the response. I will definitely try reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at the Google's page about map reduce computation model first, see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce
- http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html

It is reasonably clear, offering examples and free of all the big data buzzwords created in recent years.